# extracting the region of interest as a separate image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am working on a project where I have to detect the nostrils from thermal image of humans to detect the respiratory time, using which I can detect the respiratory rate.I have done upto the segmentation, but I am not able to extract the nostril part as a separate image. I've attached the code and the image below:

```
#import the required packages
from imutils import face_utils
import argparse
import dlib
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np

#passing the shape predictor and image thro' argparse
ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shapepredictor", required=True, help="path to find rquired facial landmark")
ap.add_argument("-img", "--image", required=True, help="path to input image")
args=vars(ap.parse_args())


detector=dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor=dlib.shape_predictor(args["shapepredictor"])

while True:
      frame=cv2.imread(args["image"])
      frame=imutils.resize(frame,width=500)
      gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      rect=detector(gray, 0)

      #detecting the face and then the nose
      for i in rect:
            x,y,w,h=face_utils.rect_to_bb(i)
            cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
            shape=predictor(gray,i)
            shape=face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

            for nx,ny in shape:
                cv2.circle(frame,(nx,ny),3,(255,0,0),-1)


      cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
      key=cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff
      if key==27:
              break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Now that I've detected the nostril part,how am I supposed to extract it as a separate image? Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Do you want just the nostrils or do you want the subset to be just containing your "dots" or to hold the "square" face bounding box?

Comment: I need just the nostrils as an image

Comment: And how would you define the nostrils? Is it based on the dots, some bounding box holding all of them or is it a certain subset of those that give you the position of the nostrils?

Comment: I actually used the ibug300W dataset to train to detect the nostrils...so based on that the nostril region can be defined as the dots as shown above, but I prefer to extract the nostril region as a separate image.

Answer (score 1):

The way you subset images is with indexing on your frame variable which is a 2d np.array.

An example would be:

```
frame=cv2.imread("somepath.jpg") # To load an image to frame
gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #To convert to 2D grayscale
RoI=gray[start_x:width,start_y:height]
```

To expand on my answer, here is a minimal functional example of image subsetting running from an image loaded by url, but using the cv2 package as you are.

```
import numpy as np
import urllib
import cv2

url='http://scipy-lectures.org/_images/sphx_glr_plot_camera_001.png'
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

cv2.imshow("Image", image[:200,:200])
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I tried doing the same..but I got an attribute error stating that  'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'left'.

Comment: @ Alexander: Is it because of the dataset that I am not able to extract the nostril using a bounding box as you said above?

Comment: Shouldn't be. If you were to just run your frame variable in the terminal, it should say something akin to:  array([[int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,]], dtype=uint8) right?

Comment: Basically your frame variable as far as i can see is an array of some size with width 500 after you resize it. As long as it is a frame you should be able to subset it.

Comment: I'll try what you've said...Thanks btw :)

Comment: Let me know if the example i added to the answer works. It really should i tested it on two of my machines, though that is no guarantee. From there i am sure you should be able to apply it to your code. But keep me updated and ill try to help

Comment: :Nope, i wasn't able to get the nostril region alone.